# Flask Rest API - How to use Bearer API token in python requests

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I have developed an API in Flask and using basic authentication token. When I testing this API with curl then bearer token accepted and API is working. But when using in python requests it is showing 401 error.

Python code used for Flask API:

```
@app.route('/api/resource')
@auth.login_required
def get_resource():
    return
```

jsonify({'data': 'Hello, %s!' % g.user.username.title()})

Testing with curl is working fine:
>

```
curl -u eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NsdfCI6MTUzMDc5MDIzNCwiZXhwIjoxNT
   MwNzkwODM0fQ.eyJpZCsf.jKiafmv-qrvAxVo7UKQuohS2vkF-9scpuqsKRuw:sp -i -X GET 
   http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/resource
   HTTP/1.0 200 OK
   Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 32
Server: Werkzeug/0.14.1 Python/3.6.4
Date: Thu, 05 Jul 2018 11:33:22 GMT
{  "data": "Hello, FlaskAPI!"}
```

Python code to consume API:

```
import requests
url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/resource"
headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    'Authorization': "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImlhsfsdfsdzNCwiZXhwIjoxNTMwNzksdfsdsdRF.eyJpZCI6MX0.YhZvjKiafmv-qrvAxVo7UKQuohS2vkF-9scpuqsKRuw"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

It shows error: 
Unauthorized Access 401

How to use Bearer token used in curl from Python or postman?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

If you want us to use Bearer tokens take a look at Miguel Grinberg's [Application Programming Interfaces](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xxiii-application-programming-interfaces-apis) and scroll down to the "Tokens in the User Model". However, the whole thing deserves a read.

Another article is Real Pythons's [Token-Based Authentication with Flask](https://realpython.com/token-based-authentication-with-flask/).

Both of these will help with understanding and implementation of bearer tokens.

Answer (score 1):

`curl -u` uses not bearer tokens but  [BasicAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) (via login and password). Try this:

```
url = 'http://%s:%s@127.0.0.1:5000/api/resource' % (
    'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImlhsfsdfsdzNCwiZXhwIjoxNTMwNzksdfsdsdRF.eyJpZCI6MX0.YhZvjKiafmv-qrvAxVo7UKQuohS2vkF-9scpuqsKRuw',
    'sp',
)
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
```

But the recommended way is passing login and password [encoded in header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side):

```
import base64
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/resource'
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic %s' % base64.b64encode('%s:%s' % (
            'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImlhsfsdfsdzNCwiZXhwIjoxNTMwNzksdfsdsdRF.eyJpZCI6MX0.YhZvjKiafmv-qrvAxVo7UKQuohS2vkF-9scpuqsKRuw',
            'sp',
        ),
    ),
}
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
```