# Okta Flask Integration

Tags: python, rest, flask, openid, okta

I want to protect my Flask REST endpoints using Okta and OpenID connect.

I have seen how to do it for routes that are views of the application, but is there a way to integrate Okta with REST endpoints?  When I make calls to my API, I get the html for Okta as a response, even if I'm logged in in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

What HTML do you get from Okta? in one case you might get a HTML page with a self-submitting form that is meant to be sent back to your client, and that's normal.

But at the same time, the openid-connect implementation in the API is different from your client applications. The API should not deal with user-redirects, instead it should only listen for access-tokens in the authorize request header. The API should for the received tokens validate them against Okta.

To add token to request, then see this question [Flask Rest API - How to use Bearer API token in python requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51192866/flask-rest-api-how-to-use-bearer-api-token-in-python-requests)

Comment: I get the HTML for the Okta login page.  For reference, I followed this tutorial: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/07/12/flask-tutorial-simple-user-registration-and-login.  The difference is that some of my routes are to display in the browser and others are to the server-side API.  How do I pass an access-token in the authorize request header?

Comment: See updated answer, hope that is an acceptable answer